# Why was my question on the AWS CLI closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm quite confused as to why my question was closed:

[How can I use wildcards to `cp` a group of files with the AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38834708/1887261)

Wouldn't this fall under "software tools primarily used by programmers"?

Comment: I voted to close because the question is asking for simple instructions on how to use a program that (IMO) is more of a systems administration tool than a programming one.

Comment: And is there value to reopening it? Are you expecting more answers? Closure is not deletion, the question will still exist to help others and give you your rep.

Comment: Is it really only used by programmers? I would think this is a popular UNIX tool used by non-programmers

Comment: If the question is rightfuly closed, then we may need to think about whether the [`[aws-cli]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cli) tag is on topic.

Comment: The question was protected then a close vote was initiated.  How many deleted answers does the question have? If I am protecting a question, there likely is a reason, many times it's received numerous answers that should never have been submitted. **What I see is numerous answers suggesting the exact same solution.** I suspect the close vote is due to the fact, "Questions about general S3 support, functionality, configuration, etc. are OFF-TOPIC", would easily be a valid description of the linked question.

Comment: @SecurityHound 3. One question-as-answer, one answer-comment-as-answer, one self-deleted answer attempt - which is probably about par for the course for a popular question

Comment: @CertainPerformance - 125K views is a popular question after 8 years? That's less than 1,302 views a month. To be frank outside of the answer from 2016, the rest of the answers are just duplicates of the original answer, the question overall is pretty low quality in my opinion. In fact it seems the user guide, if referenced before the question was asked, likely would have resulted in the question not being asked.

Comment: That an answer for the problem exists in the documentation, however, isn't a reason for closure, nor for the question to not exist, @SecurityHound ; [so] aims to be a complete repository of questions and that will include "simple" *documented* problems too. Of course, if it *is* clearly documented, that could be seen as a reason to downvote the question, due to an (apparent) lack of research.

Comment: While the official docs do answer this, for better or worse, this question is the top hit for a query of [aws cli cp wildcard](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+cli+copy+wildcard).  While this is absolutely something non-developers would want to know, it also feels to me like the start of many an ad-hoc script or program creation, so it seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  FWIW, I wasn't concerned about rep or anything, just curious.  Also, FWIW in response to the top comment, I am a software engineer and I barely do any sys admin stuff, but use the AWS CLI extensively, daily.

Comment: I mean... I'm a web developer, and when working on AWS related projects I do routinely use the AWS CLI, but I'd never call that programming or consider it a programming related task.

Comment: Where would you say Docker CLI related questions would belong?  Similarly to `aws-cli` stack overflow is the first place I'd think to look.  I'm mainly going with the `software tools primarily used by programmers` guidance.

Comment: twitter maybe? I'm not really concerned where users ask questions unrelated to SO's purpose.

Comment: To be absolutely clear, the opinion i'm expressing here related to CLI's being on topic is mine, and most certainly doesn't represent any form of majority. The on-topic-ness of CLI questions would deserve it's own meta question

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I thought you were expressing a majority opinion, which is why I ducked out.

Comment: I'll weigh in and say `aws cli cp` is nothing like `cp`. There are certain aws cli operations which are [not replicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251412/is-there-a-simple-way-to-rename-s3-folder-via-boto3) using higher level libraries like boto3, or for which the cli operations are more performant. I, as a programmer use these extensively in my day job. (1/2)

Comment: Questions [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192391/how-do-i-find-the-total-size-of-my-aws-s3-storage-bucket-or-folder) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590403/1456253) are [invaluable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888507/how-to-move-all-files-and-folder-from-one-folder-to-another-of-s3-bucket-in-php). I would caution throwing the babe out with the bathwater on this one. (2/2)

Comment: It appears the babe has been thrown out

Comment: This feels wrong. I thought the whole point was to wait for consensus on meta before acting. There's one answer here, which says... maybe. Really guys?

Comment: Sadly there's no interaction of the closevoters on this meta question. So we don't even know their reasoning. Their input would be quite important in this discussion.

Comment: I honestly don't think it would be useful, as people are pretty entrenched in their opinions on whether or not a CLI is programming related.

Comment: My reasoning is a CLI isn't a coding language. There's no logic to work out. At most, questions related to CLI usage are just a failure to use documentation. There is no logic to work out, no problems to solve, it's a 1:1 here's the documentation for what you're trying to do scenario. It isn't useful to replicate documentation in a location that (likely) won't be updated when the CLI changes. It's more likely question/answer pairs like this will provide incorrect information long-term. Even your own examples have outdated answers that haven't been fixed/deleted.

Comment: My reasoning is that a API and a CLI are only superficially different. Both absolutely do have logic to work out. What inputs do and how they work together can be very unexpected. Just like any API, answers here are scoped to the version of cli they belong to. Keeping answers up to date is a general problem SO has and is not limited to questions like this.

Comment: I generally feel the same way about API's. Interacting with an api is certainly on topic, but what endpoints to use to do X Y or Z... not so much. For CLI's, how to use them programmatically would be, but which arguments to use to do x y or z... not so much... unless it's something like git where it's a tool primarily used for programming.

Comment: Is it worth opening a different question to discuss where `aws-cli` questions belong? If my question doesn't belong on SO, then there are many, many others that do not belong as well.

Answer (score 14):

*Honestly*...  I dunno if this question should be closed or not.

*Yes*, it's using a common function that most Unix developers would be doing.  But if you asked someone to do this in AWS and *all they have* is Unix experience, there's a non-trivial amount of tension that comes along with said request.

Because *yes*, on its surface it looks a whole heck a lot [like the copy](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) we know and love in Unix land.  But [if I look at the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) I panic a little at reading "metadata".

I'd conjecture based on this, the question *shouldn't* be closed *just because* it's dealing with a familiar-looking-but-definitely-not-the-same-thing-kind of command.

But the issue at hand is probably less about this specific question being off-topic and more about the AWS CLI being off-topic.

To that I'd say, probably not, that feels like it's on-topic too.  AWS programmers would want or need to know how to do things with this tool.

But if we feel passionate about this, maybe we need to revisit what is and isn't on-topic for AWS?

Answer (score 2):

This question should not be closed. I believe that AWS CLI questions should be on topic. <s>I also believe that closing the question while its being discussed here on meta is not the right way of doing things.</s> (The question was already closed before this discussion)

Copying my logic from the comments:

It seems like the two arguments for closure are 1) since `cp` is off topic, `aws cli cp` should be as well, obviously its only something Linux users would use! and 2) Questions about general S3 support, functionality, configuration are off topic.

1. Despite its *similar* appearance and interface, `aws cp` is significantly different from its built in counterpart. There are certain aws cli operations which are not replicable using higher level libraries like boto3, or for which the cli operations are more performant. I, as a programmer use these extensively in my day job.

   I challenge you to do anything on bulk s3 data (or data in an s3 'folder') in a performant manner without cli operations (move, rename, version, etc). And thats exactly what the question linked to is talking about.
2. I interpret this as being a question about the API, not about the general workings of the service. If I were to make a library used by programmers, and solely provide a cli for it rather than language bindings, questions about that library would still be on-topic. Thats exactly whats happened here.

Comment: *I also believe that closing the question while its being discussed here on meta is not the right way of doing things.*: It was closed before the meta post, then it was reopened and reclosed after the post. If you say that closing questions while the discussion is ongoing is not OK, then certainly reopening is also not.

Comment: ^ Good context. I agree, I would just worry about it being deleted while being discussed, since that would limit who could see it.

Comment: Deletion of a post this popular would require quite a few votes from a very small pool of users (that can't even vote to delete yet on this post.) It is *not* at risk